# how do i create a debuggable axis2 project in eclipse using maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-axis

I followed the tutorial at [this link](http://www.itcuties.com/j2ee/axis2-java2wsdl-approach/) to create a axis2 webservice project using maven and eclipse.

However, this setup doesn't allow me to debug my code. Can someone point me to a link which will allow me to use maven to build my axis2 webservice and debug the code inside eclipse?

Comment: What have you done so far?  Do you have services deployed within axis2.war within Tomcat?

Comment: @davidfmatheson - yes i have all of that setup. My only problem is that the setup in this tutorial gives me an aar which i will have to drop in my WEB-INF/services/ folder of my tomcat.  Is there a way I can drop the aar inside my project somewhere so that i can debug the relevant source code?

Comment: Are you running Tomcat from within Eclipse, or outside of it?

Comment: im using tomcat within eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Tomcat within Eclipse, then perhaps it's just a matter of putting the project on the source lookup path.  Because you're not deploying it as a `.war` in Tomcat, it's just deployed as an `.aar` within the `axis2.war` deployment.  Try this:

1. `Run` -> `Debug Configurations...`
2. Select your Tomcat instance under `Apache Tomcat`
3. Select the `Source` tab
4. Click the `Add...` button
5. Select `Java Project` and then `HighScoreService`

You should be able to put a breakpoint in the code and debug it.  I put a breakpoint on line 21 of `HighScoreService.java`, invoked `getHighScores` from SoapUI, and was able to debug.

Comment: this worked but I had to import the axis2 war in eclipse and drop the aar inside the WEB-INF/services of the project containing the axis2 war.

Comment: with the current setup is there a way to automatically generate the services.xml file?

Comment: I didn't have to import `axis2.war` into my project to get this to work.  Generating `services.xml` seems like an option on the `maven-wsdl2code-plugin` axis2 plugin, but I'm not sure how you would tell it to take the WSDL it generated from `java2wsdl`.

Comment: i commented out the step in the `pom.xml` to generate the `services.xml` file and the wsdl/aar generates just fine.